# How to see this limit of parameters holds in an integral after taking the integral instead of before?

Tags: integration, limits

Suppose $b_2, b_1 > 0$. I have the following integral:

$$\frac{1}{(b_2-b_1)^2}\int_{t_1}^{t_2}(e^{(b_1-b_2)t_1} - e^{(b_1-b_2)t})(e^{(b_2-b_1)t_2} - e^{(b_2-b_1)t})dt$$.

Before we take the integral, we see that if $b_1 \to b_2 \neq 0$, then the integral will converge to a finite value because each term in the product integrand is approximately proportional to $(b_2 - b_1)$ (without higher order terms). One way to see this is with Taylor series. However, if the integral is evaluated directly with respect to $t$, then it isn't obvious (at least to me) that this integral formula should converge in the limit as $b_1 \to b_2 \neq 0$, because of the multiplicative term $1/(b_2 - b_1)^2$. Is there an obvious way to see (Taylor serres, ?) after taking the integral directly that the limit as $b_1 \to b_2 \neq 0$ exists, and what that integral value should be as $b_1 \to b_2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per discussion comments, the quantity does converge.  This answer has been edited a bit to fix the problem.

Denote $\Delta b=b_1-b_2$.  If you multiply out the integrand, you will see that it is equal to $$e^{\Delta b(t_1-t_2)}-e^{\Delta b(t_1-t)}-e^{\Delta b(t-t_2)}+1.$$  You get that constant $1$ because the second term in each parenthesis of your integrand are reciprocals; $e^{(b_1-b_2)t}e^{(b_2-b_1)t}=1.$  Therefore, we are interested in calculating $$I=\frac{1}{\Delta b^2}\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \left(e^{\Delta b(t_1-t_2)}-e^{\Delta b(t_1-t)}-e^{\Delta b(t-t_2)}+1\right) dt$$ The integral gives us $$(t_2-t_1)e^{\Delta b(t_1-t_2)}+\frac{1}{\Delta b}\left(e^{\Delta b(t_1-t_2)}-1\right)-\frac{1}{\Delta b}\left(1-e^{\Delta b(t_1-t_2)}\right)+(t_2-t_1).$$  Therefore, in total, after some factoring, we get $$I=\frac{1}{\Delta b^2}\left((t_2-t_1)\left[e^{\Delta b(t_1-t_2)}+1\right]\right)+\frac{2}{\Delta b^3}\left(e^{\Delta b(t_1-t_2)}-1\right).$$  As $\Delta b\rightarrow 0$, this is an indeterminate form; taking a common factor of $\Delta b$ and applying L'Hospital's rule twice (as each step is an indeterminate form of the same type) results in $$\lim_{\Delta b \rightarrow 0}I=\lim_{\Delta b\rightarrow 0}\frac{(t_1-t_2)^2e^{\Delta b(t_1-t_2)}\Delta b (t_2-t_1)}{6\Delta b}=\frac{(t_2-t_1)^3}{6}$$

Comment: Either by using linear Taylor polynomials on the two integrand factors in the product before taking the integral, or by just coding up the computed anti-derivative function in something like MATLAB and plugging in values of $b_1$ very close to $b_2 \neq 0$, it does seem to converge as $b_1 \to b_2 \neq 0$..

Comment: I don't know what to tell you.  I just threw the indefinite integral into WolframAlpha, and it gave $\displaystyle\frac{bt(e^{b(t_1-t_2)}+1)+e^{b(t_1-t)}-e^{b(t-t_2)}}{b}$, which is consistent with my answer, once you evaluate the definite integral.  Here, I've written $(b_1-b_2)=b$.

Comment: What is the coded antiderivative you used that lead you to make your previous comment?

Comment: I believe the antiderivative I got was the same, and I agree, it didn't look like it should converge to me as $b_1 \to b_2 \neq 0$. I recommend just plugging in $t_1 = 1$, $t_2 = 2$, and $b_1 = 1$ and $b_2$ trying $b_2 = 1 + \epsilon$ where e.g. you keep dividing $\epsilon$ by 10 starting with something like $\epsilon = 0.1$, and then evaluating the definite integral in a tool like WolframAlpha and checking that it appears to converge to a finite value as $\epsilon$ becomes smaller and smaller.

Comment: @Kevin_Church I've checked and double-checked and the only thing I can't figure out is how the limit exists after you take the integral. But clearly for $b_1$ close to $b_2$, the function you are integrating with respect to $t$ is basically $(t_2 - t)(t - t_1)$ after canceling the constant terms in the Taylor expansions with respect to $(b_2 - b_1)$ and then canceling the divide by $(b_2 - b_1)^2$ by the multiplication of two factors of $(b_2 - b_1)$ appearing after the constant terms cancel in the two Taylor series before you take the integral.

Comment: I think I might have identified an error in the last line of my answer.  Correcting...

Comment: You're completely correct.  I lost a term when I applied L'Hospital's rule.  I will modify my answer accordingly.  It does converge.